# Adding transparency to a TIFF using colormaps

Tags: c++, tiff

I have an 8-bit image I write as a TIFF where I specify the color map using the following code:

```
// given the name of a colormap, get the values as r,g,b,a,....
const vector<unsigned char>& cmap = getColormap(colormap);
assert(cmap.size() == 256 * 4);

unsigned short red[256], green[256], blue[256];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    const size_t j = i * 4;
    red[i] = cmap[j];
    green[i] = cmap[j+1];
    blue[i] = cmap[j+2];
}
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_PALETTE);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COLORMAP, red, green, blue);
```

This works very well and produces the images as expected. However, I am having trouble locating any tutorials or reference material that explains how to go about setting up a color map with transparency too. At very least, I'd like the color index of 0 to be fully transparent.

Comment: Afaik you cannot do this in a straightforward way. You could try to have an extra sample per pixel in the image data itself (so each pixel would be [index, alpha]), but the colormap itself has no support for alpha.